# How to define list of dictionaries in a struct

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I want to load JSON that contains a list of dictionary, for example

```
{error: false, "objects": [{"id": 1, "name": "cat"}, {"id": 2, "name": "dog"}, {"id": 3, "name": "fish"}]
```

How could this be defined in a

```
struct name: Codable, Identifiable  {
}
```

to be used in JSONDecoder to decode the received data.
How can the struct be written to define this datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct data: Codable {
   let error: Bool
   let objects: [dataObjects]
}

struct dataObjects: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

Comment: How could I use the array in a SwiftUI List?  
After getting the json in a different file and import it in ContentView using @ State var posts: [Post] = []